# Capture barcode reader event on Honeywell 75e and phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create an android application with phonegap and Cordova. I have got a Honeywell device 75e on which the app will be running. I have got to the point where by which if I press the scan button on the device, the bar code gets printed into the textbox which is in focus. However what I want to do is that when the scanner button is pressed and the bar code has been read using the internal scanner on the device,  the application should go to the next page. I was thinking of adding a on key  event on the input box itself but I cannt really do that as the user of the application can type the text in the textbox and then press the go button.
Is there a way to find out the keycode  for the scanner button on the device and if there is then I could modify the application to look for the key code and fire the fake button click event. 
Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I have figured it out how to get around this but posting it here for anyone who is stuck as well. If you log into the honeywell technical support portal, (login is free) you can get the web API SDK which allows you to communicate with the hardware. It adds listeners to the bar code and also has additional functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out how to get around this but posting it here for anyone who is stuck as well. If you log into the honeywell technical support portal, (login is free) you can get the web API SDK which allows you to communicate with the hardware. It adds listeners to the bar code and also has additional functions.